# What are the chances that a well shuffled deck of cards has no more than 2 cards of the same color consecutively?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

### Questions

I was watching a Penn & Teller Fool Us clip, and Paul Gertner has a trick where he starts with a deck that is supposedly shuffled. I noticed, however, that there is no instance where there are more than two reds or more than two blacks consecutively. In fact, the cards appear in a consistent pattern of $...,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,...$ where 2 is a block of two cards of the same color.

You can see the sequence of cards [here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=OVkmibfFbVI&t=1m10s) , if you like.

Assume you begin with a fairly and completely shuffled deck, then what are the chances of:

1. No color appearing more than twice in a row?
2. The pattern $...,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,...$  appearing through the entire deck?

---

#### Edit: Extra info for anyone that loves puzzles, math, and/or magic

[Here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=OVkmibfFbVI&t=1m10s) is the sequence of cards in the trick.

Notice first that the sequence follows the questions posed above. Namely, that the entire sequence is of the form $...brrbrrbbrbbrbbrr...$ where $b$ is a black card and $r$ is a red card.

This may also be expressed as $...,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,...$ where $1 \in \{b, r\}$ and $2 \in \{bb, rr\}$.

Then consider, in addition:

- In each block of 2 cards, the suit is the same.
- For each adjacent block of 1 or 2 cards, the suits are always different.
- In fact, treating each 2-block as one card, then the pattern of suits is $...,c, d, s, h, c, d, s, h,...$ where $c$ is clubs, $d$ is diamonds, $s$ is spades, and $h$ is hearts.
- In all single card blocks, the card's value is $\in \{6, 7, 8\}$ (in the section shown in this clip).
- Where $x$ and $y$ are the numeric values of two different cards with $x, y \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13\}$, and an ace has a value of 1, a jack of 11, a queen of 12, and a king of 13, and the difference between the values of a two card block is defined as:
  $$D(x,y) = {| x-y |}$$
  Notice that $D(x,y) = 8$ for all two card blocks.

There are some tough and interesting counting/probability problems in there. It would be a very complex counting problem indeed to determine the chances of all of those conditions being true. There may be even more patterns I haven't noticed, as well. I don't know why the deck is arranged that way for the purposes of the trick, but it's an interesting puzzle!

Comment: This will be a fun question to work on. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Does $1-2-1-2-2$ mean $rbbrbbrr$/$brrbrrbb$ or something else?

Comment: @TheCount I think the second question is much easier than the first!

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Exactly.

Comment: @AdamB, yes, I think so too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rough estimate:

Considering only the first three cards, the probability of three equal colours is approximately $\frac14$; the precise value  $\frac{52\cdot 25\cdot 24}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50}=\frac 4{17}$ differs a bit from this because the colours are not independent. Fortunately, expected values are additive even in case of dependency. Therefore, we *expect* $50\cdot\frac 4{17}\approx 11.8$ instances of three consecutive cards of same colour.

Going by rule of thumb, we may estimate that this number is distributed with mean and variance both $=11.8$. So *zero* instances is about $3.4$ standard deviations too low - and that is *very* unlikely.

### Less hand-wavy:

Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of ways to break a line $n$ same-colour cards into $k$ pieces of length $1$ or $2$.
We have the recursion
$$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k-1)+f(n-2,k-1) $$
and clearly, $f(n,k)=0$ if $k>n$ or $2k<n$. The recursion reminds of binomial coefficients, and indeed we find that 
$$ f(n,k)={k\choose n-k}.$$
If our deck has $k$ blocks of red cards (each of length $1$ or $2$), then it can have

- $k-1$ blocks of black cards in-between the reds
- $k+1$ blocks of black cards with the red blocks in-between the black blocks
- $k$ blocks of black and the first block is red, the last black
- $k$ blocks of black and the first block is black, the last red

Hence the total way to have a 52 card deck  without blocks longer than $2$ is
$$\begin{align} \sum_k f(26,k)\cdot& \left(f(26,k-1)+f(26,k+1)+2f(26,k)\right)
\\&=\sum_k {k\choose 26-k}\cdot \left({k-1\choose 27-k}+{k-1\choose 25-k}+2{k\choose 26-k}\right)\end{align}$$
where we need only $k=13, \ldots, 26$.
Evaluating this and dividing by $\frac{52!}{26!^2}$, we arrive at a probability of 
$$ \frac{23246263956\cdot 26!^2}{52!}=\frac{1937188663}{41326544412342}\approx 0.000047.$$

---

### Fixed prescribed red/black pattern

For a fixed prescribed red/black pattern the answer is much simpler: If we prescribe which cards are red and which are black, there are $26!^2$ "good" sequences out of $52!$ in total. We arrive at a probability of $\frac{26!^2}{52!}\approx 2\cdot 10^{-15}$.

Comment: can you elaborate on "the precise value is 4/17 because the colur are not independent" not sure I got the 4/17 number. Thanks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Really great, well worked solutions. Thank you so much! I'll mark resolved once I can fully understand the recursively defined solution to the first question. Nice magic pun in the subheading, by the way! (:

Comment: @adhg Consider a set of three cards as a "hand" of three cards. When three cards are dealt out of a full deck, there are (52*51*50) possible hands. To calculate the probability of a 3-hand of a single color, take the number of ways to get a single color 3-hand from a full deck (52*25*24) then divide by the possible hands. Then 31,200 / 132,600 = 4/17.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen got it. thanks

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I posted a section to your de.wikipedia.org user page. Please check it out!

Comment: @AdamB If you have a concrete question about my answer, you should try a comment here. It is certainly possible that some mistake lures in there. -- But if you deem it appropriate to crosspost elsewhere, *please* include a link to the original question (i,e,, here) - did you know that there are several users named "Adam B" on this site? -- Finally, if you have obtained an alternative solution elsewhere, you are welcome (the author permitting) to post it as additional answer here.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I wanted to send you a PDF file, which I can't do via stackexchange. I don't have a specific question, nor do I believe that there is any mistake in your solution. I appreciate it very much that you wrote up this solution. I would simply like to have you take a look at this other solution which comes up with essentially the same answer but in a totally different way. The man who wrote this other solution is a very good mathematician, and I'm interested to see what you think of his solution because you are clearly well versed on the topic as well. Thanks, Hagen.